# I'm having troubles when trying to install "mingw-w64 GCC" under Win 11 with "$ pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc"

Tags: c++, msys2

```
# pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (15) mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-binutils-2.41-2
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crt-git-11.0.0.r239.g037ba0184-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-libs-13.2.0-2  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gmp-6.3.0-2
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-headers-git-11.0.0.r239.g037ba0184-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-isl-0.26-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libiconv-1.17-3
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-11.0.0.r239.g037ba0184-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-mpc-1.3.1-2  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-mpfr-4.2.1-2
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-windows-default-manifest-6.4-4
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-winpthreads-git-11.0.0.r239.g037ba0184-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zlib-1.3-1  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zstd-1.5.5-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-13.2.0-2

Total Download Size:    49.38 MiB
Total Installed Size:  418.89 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-13.2.0-2-any.pkg.tar.zst failed to download
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-binutils-2.41-2-any.pkg.tar.zst failed to download
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-headers-git-11.0.0.r239.g037ba0184-1-any.pkg.tar.zst failed to download
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crt-git-11.0.0.r239.g037ba0184-1-any.pkg.tar.zst failed to download
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-isl-0.26-1-any.pkg.tar.zst failed to download
 Total ( 5/15)                    49.4 MiB  2.21 MiB/s 00:22 [###############################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-13.2.0-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 470 ms: Couldn't connect to server
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-binutils-2.41-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 469 ms: Couldn't connect to server
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-headers-git-11.0.0.r239.g037ba0184-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.msys2.org : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 468 ms: Couldn't connect to server

(...)

warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

**It was suggested in a comment that I execute** `pacman-mirrors ...` **There seems to be no such executable in my system:**

```
# pacman-mirrors -f5
-bash: pacman-mirrors: command not found
```

**It is also suggested that I load the certificates again with** `pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ca-certificates*`, **but:**

```
# pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ca-certificates*
loading packages...
error: '/var/cache/pacman/pkg/ca-certificates*': could not find or read package
```

Comment: You can also install WSL2 and install GCC there. You can also integrate VSCode to work with WSL using Remote extensions.

Comment: My guess would be a firewall or proxy getting in the way

Comment: Some network issue prevents you from reaching the mirror. Maybe switching to an alternative mirror would help, see [this](https://www.msys2.org/dev/mirrors/) (edit `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.*` to put a different mirror as the first one).

Comment: @kiner_shah Yeah, but then you can't distribute the resulting binaries to Windows users. :/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yeah that's right, a problem if that's the goal.